# Box has 3 sets of wires and I’m trying to convert what was a single gang into a dual gang

Tags: electrical

I have 3 sets of wires, each set has one hot & one neutral, coming into the same box. One incoming, two outgoing.

I want power for two switches to control fixture (*one for light switch, one for ceiling fan*).

Previously this box only had one switch.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please clarify your statement "I want power for two receptacles to control fixture (one for light switch, one for ceiling fan)"? Receptacles don't "control" things, they allow you to plug corded devices into them and they do not have anything to do with light switches (unless the receptacle is wired to be controlled by a switch) or ceiling fans....

Comment: Apologies, it’s for light switches.

Comment: @Matt We do not have enough info.  We do not know what the 3 sets of wires are for and why they are in this box. **What was the box for, How were the wires connected before?**  You need to explain exactly what the situation was, Preferable with photos,  and a **very detailed explanation** of what you want to accomplish. *I edit it for correct terms as best i could divine your intentions*.

Comment: Can't do photos because I don't remember what it looked like originally. This was a single-gang box controlling a ceiling fan/light fixture. The one switch powered the device. I wanted to change to two switches, one for the light and one for the fan.

If I remember correctly, all three hots and all three neutrals were nutted together and then pigtailed to the switch. I'm trying to accomplish having two switches, one for the light and one for the fan. I've removed the old single-gang box, cut the wall, and installed the dual-gang box.

Comment: Can we assume that what you had before was: 1. Three white wires nutted together?  2. Three blacks nutted together with one being a short pigtail to the switch itself?  3. The last black wire coming from the switch and disappearing into one of the cables?  Sound correct?  And I gather they're now all disconnected and splayed all over the place and you have no idea which is which?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box as it stands now?  Also, can you post photos of the insides of the other boxes associated with this?